# Severe speed problem between Ubutu Mate 21.10 and Hughsnet satellite internet service

Tags: networking, google-chrome, mate

I have a severe speed problem that I've been fighting for over 6 months.  I have Hughsnet satellite internet, their premium high speed package.  I have two Dell Optiplex computers, different year models and a Samsung Galaxy S20 cellphone.  Ubuntu Mate 20.10 and one revision earlier on the other.

Using testmy.net, the only speed test Hughsnet will accept for a complaint I get between 20 and 50 Mbps.  About 30 on the cellphone.

But on the 2 Ubuntu machines, when using either Firefox or Chrome, I get no more than 50 KILObytes/sec. Youtube never does over 50kib and buffers continuously.  Wget is just a little faster.

What I've done so far.  Reinstalled with purge Firefox and Chrome.  Reinstalled with purge network-control.  Started a virgin Firefox and Chrome with no plugins.  I've ordered a new hard drive to do a pure installation and see what happens.  If that fixes it I'm in a world of hurt.  I have I have over a decade's worth of data and packages and code I've written on that drive.  Is there anything I can do short of a complete new install to try and recover this.  Maybe reinstall the entire network stack?

Halp!!!

### Thanks,
John

posting tracepaths here because there isn't sufficient room in a comment.

```
jgd@den:~$ tracepath youtube.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  _gateway                                              0.254ms 
 1:  _gateway                                              0.249ms 
 2:  host9773008054.direcway.com                         569.092ms 
 3:  host9773005052.direcway.com                         945.836ms 
 4:  ae7-122.bar1.SaltLakeCity1.Level3.net               660.547ms 
 5:  ae3.3.bar3.SaltLakeCity1.level3.net                 779.948ms asymm  6 
 6:  142.250.166.180                                     1033.919ms asymm  7 
 6:  142.250.166.180                                     623.024ms asymm  7 
 7:  no reply


jgd@den:~$ tracepath amazon.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1500
 1:  _gateway                                              0.400ms 
 1:  _gateway                                              0.284ms 
 2:  host9773008054.direcway.com                         730.251ms 
 3:  host9773005052.direcway.com                         1748.907ms 
 3:  host9773005052.direcway.com                         1749.023ms 
 4:  ae7-122.bar1.SaltLakeCity1.Level3.net               1176.947ms 
 5:  ae2.3615.edge1.Dallas2.level3.net                   767.699ms asymm  9 
 6:  99.82.183.118                                       617.865ms asymm  9 
 7:  no reply
 8:  no reply
```

Comment: How is download speed with `apt`, `curl` or `wget`? Is it just GUI-based software that is set to ISDN speeds? 

Comment: MTU trouble? Install and run `tracepath` to check your `pmtu` (Path MTU). Read `man ip ip-link`, and check the Hughsnet docs for "MTU"

Comment: You don't need to *" I've ordered a new hard drive to do a pure installation and see what happens"*... just boot to a Ubuntu Live USB and retest. @waltinator idea about checking your MTU is a good idea too.

Comment: Would you mind being a bit more verbose with your MTU trouble testing.  I'm a nuclear and electrical engineer and not a network admin.  Where would I find the Hughsnet MTU docs?  I've spent a couple of hours on this already this morning and am confused and have not found the docs.

My Galaxy S20 phone is similarly slow.  Does that affect your proposed diagnostics?

Final question.  How is the web application testmy.net getting around this problem?  Do they use udp packets or something.

Thanks
John

Comment: I tried testmy.net. It uses TCP for both upload and download tests. Where are the 2 tracepaths?

Comment: I posted the tracepaths in my original question because there isn't enough room in a comment.

Comment: Yes, editing your question and putting requested stuff there is what you are supposed to do. It wasn't there when I made my comment. @waltinator might not see it unless you ping him, which I am doing herein.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution to this problem and it had little to do with download settings.  I optimized my MTu using the procedure given here using ping.  That helped a little.

In frustration, I logged into the Hughsnet modem with the intention of changing every setting a little to see what difference it made.

Log into your modem, then advanced setup -> QoS Quality of Service for **upload** traffic.  That seemed odd.  QoS was not enabled.  None of the "allow more" boxes were checked.  So I checked them all

**VOILA!!!**

All problems gone.  The fastest testmy.net has reported is 80Mbs!!

There is still a problem with the modem firmware because it behaves the same on my ethernet computer and my phone.  About once a day I have to disconnect my ethernet connection and reconnect.  Not physically but the up-down arrows on the upper task bar.  Click "disconnect".  Click the arrows again, then "wired connection 1".  If I don't do that, the most I see is about 5 Mbps.  it's almost autopilot to do that first thing when I sit down.

One other thing.  It greatly improves things to power cycle the modem about once a week.  I bought an appliance wireless remote control so all I have to do is press the "off" button on the dongle on my desk and then "on".

We were all looking in the wrong places.  It wasn't a download problem, it was an **upload** problem.

Hallelujah!!!  I've been fighting this problem for years.  Finally, I can stream video without buffering and not have to wait overnight for a new release to download.

John

Comment: An upload problem wouldn't cause your video to buffer.

Comment: Sorry, but you're absolutely, positively flat wrong.  Protocols like what testmy-net use sends little upstream traffic (as determined by Wire-Shark) flew before.  Web traffic that sends large amount of upstream traffic creeps along.  After spending several days with WireShark, I learned that download speed limits when the upload bandwidth ACKs are limited.  The existence proof is when I turn QoS off, the browser slows to less than 100kbps.   When I check the QoS box, browser speed shoots to as much as 8Mbps late night.